# Function to read a row indicating the relevant currency and then applying the exchange rate to a different column

Tags: r

I am attempting to convert a metric (EMV) which is listed in various currencies into dollars for an easy like-for-like comparison

Here's the structure of the data As it stands I have columns

```
str(df)

(...)

$ EMV                           : num  120 0 0 0 0 2 11 0 2 0 ...

$ USD.AUD                       : num  1.35 1.27 1.36 1.2 1.35 ...

$ USD.ZAR                       : num  15.1 11.9 13.1 11.5 12.4 ...

$ USD.CLF                       : num  0.0246 0.0246 0.0246 0.025 0.0246 ...

$ USD.COP                       : num  2958 2479 2898 2371 2779 ...

$ USD.MXN                       : num  18.5 15.2 16.4 14.5 16.1 ...

$ USD.UYU                       : num  30.7 26.7 29.4 23.9 27.6 ...

$ USD.EUR                       : num  0.887 0.9 0.879 0.803 0.915 ...

$ USD.GBP                       : num  0.698 0.639 0.646 0.636 0.641 ...

$ Currency                      : Factor w/ 9 levels "CLP","COP","EUR",..
```

My questions is, what syntax, script of function can i use that would read through the currency column to understand which currency rate to reference, and then divide the EMV column by the appropriate exchange rate?

If you need any additional information or data please do let me know.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Comment: Effectively I want to look through the currency column, read "EUR" or any of the other currency codes and look up the relevant EUR conversion rate (along the same row) and divide the EMV value by this conversion rate.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format my text very well on this site as of yet. I tried to make an example but it's ugly as hell...